# How to add a message as an attachment on another message with javax.mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-message, rfc2822

I've got a mailer daemon that check a box and fetch the mails inside every X mins.
When an error occurs, I need to send a alert mail, with the faulty message as an attachment.

I dont want to create a file, write the content from the original message and then add the file to the error message, I want to directly set the MimeBodyPart content from the original stream.
I already did this some years ago, so I know it's possible, I just can't remember the exact syntax to copy the message stream to the MimeBodyPart and set the content type ( which is RFC2822 )

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Have you asked google for how to attach a file using JavaMaiL?

Comment: I dont want to attach a file. I want to create a MimeMassage BodyPart from the original javax.mail.Message object, without storing it to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution that I found:

```
 MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
 mbp.setContent(forwardedMsg, "message/rfc822");
 mp.addPart(mbp);
```